# How can I pass the salt to Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing OAuth 2.0 in spring boot. When a user passes his username/password, spring tries to authenticate it by hashing the password and comparing it with the already hashed one that I pass it. But, Spring always misses the salt, so it always returns bad credentials.

**How can I pass the salt to Spring?**

Here is my UserDAO class:

```
@Service
public class UserDAO implements UserDetailsService, SaltSource{

private LoginDetails user;
private UserDetailsImpl userDetailsImpl;

@Autowired
private LoginDetailsManager loginDetailsManager;

@Override
public UserDetails1 loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    System.out.println("Get user");
    user = loginDetailsManager.getByUsername(username);
    System.out.println(user.toString());
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                "User " + username + " not found.");
    }

    GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(grantedAuthority);

    String password = user.getPasswordHash();
    String salt = user.getSalt();
    userDetailsImpl = new UserDetailsImpl(user.getUsername(), user.getPasswordHash(), salt, grantedAuthorities);

    return new UserDetailsImpl(
            user.getUsername(),
            user.getPasswordHash(),
            salt,
            grantedAuthorities);
}
}
```

Following is my AuthorizationServer class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected class AuthorizationApplication extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Bean
    protected AuthorizationCodeServices getAuthorizationCodeServices() {
        return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        AuthorizationCodeServices services = getAuthorizationCodeServices();
        JdbcTokenStore tokenStore = getTokenStore();
        endpoints
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .authorizationCodeServices(services)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .approvalStoreDisabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
        security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
```

From a little debugging, I found that Spring gets its salt from `SaltSource` (org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.SaltSource). I'm unable to figure out how can I configure that source.

Comment: Because I have SHA256(hash+password) in my database - which I'm returning from UserDAO class to Spring as property `user.getPasswordHash()` of UserDetailsImpl object. Spring is comparing it with SHA256(password) and I'm being unauthorized.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Currently, I have a manually populated database for testing. How would spring authenticate without salt?

Comment: Okay, please bear with me. To avoid complexity, I just created a new class which implements PasswordEncoder (with two methods - encode for simple sha256 hashing, and matches()) and start using it instead of StandardPasswordEncoder. Is there a way I can configure a SaltSource for that?

Comment: I was implementing `PasswordEncoder`, but in the class `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, I found this: **Salt value must be null when used with crypto module PasswordEncoder**. Doesn't make sense to implement it anymore. Is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: If you are using BCryptPasswordEncoder then you don't have to worry about salting as it is going to salt your passwords automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't figure out a way, therefore implemented my own `PasswordEncoder` and used a static variable to pass salt from the `UserDAO`:

```
public class PasswordEncoderImpl implements PasswordEncoder {

    public static Constants constants = new Constants();

    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
        return DigestUtils.sha256Hex(rawPassword.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
        String salt = constants.getSalt();

/**
 * If salt is null, it means the value in constants object is empty now.
 * => client-secret validation is going on
 * => we just need the comparision of plain-text string.
 */
        if(salt != null) {
//    case of password authentication
            return DigestUtils.sha256Hex(salt + rawPassword).equalsIgnoreCase(encodedPassword);
        } else {
    //case of client-secret authentication
        return rawPassword.equals(encodedPassword);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Setting the value of constants object in the `loadUserByUsername` method.